# Two different substitutions give two answers. Definite integral

Tags: integration

[image]

Not sure where I am going wrong with the second method, looks like I have a factor of $\frac{1}{3}$ carried in there somewhere. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Edit: In the first method I wrote $du= \frac{1}{4} dx$

Should have been $dx = \frac{1}{4} du$

Comment: When you change the variables you should change the limits of integral

Comment: Moreover, in the first should be du=4dx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second substitution you must not take $(4x - 6)$ out of the integral. Instead you will have to transform this into a function of $u$ and inlude this into your integration:
$$
u = \frac{5}{4x-6} \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx} = -\frac{20}{(4x-6)^2} = -\frac{20}{25}u^2 \Rightarrow dx = -\frac{25}{20}u^{-2} du
$$
thus
$$
\int\limits^1_0(u(x))^2dx = \int\limits^{u(1)}_{u(0)}u^2 \frac{du}{dx} du = -\frac{25}{20}\int\limits^{u(1)}_{u(0)}u^2 u^{-2} du = \frac{25}{20}\int\limits^{u(0)}_{u(1)}du.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first Substitution $u = 4x - 6$, $du = 4 dx$

In the second substitution: $u = \frac{5}{4x -6}$, $du = -20(4x-6)^{-2} dx$